# How tuning ompl parameters?

Tags: ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know that OMPL performance can be improved by tuning parameters in planning.yaml file, but which are those parametros? and how can be setting?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50161/how-tuning-ompl-parameters?/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Configuring%20a%20joint%20space%20planner) and [its sequel](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Launching%20a%20joint%20space%20planner).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1